# run build on cc.net if definite words are included to a commit log

Tags: svn, msbuild, nunit, webdriver, cruisecontrol.net

I have system of:

- svn - control version
- cc.net - as ci server
- msbuild - as a build system
- nunit - for launch test
- webdriver - for web-testing.

Now my tests are run automatically after each commit. But i want that my test run if commit has comment #runautotest (or another).

I investigated triggers of cc.net but its are for another goals.
I try to found some information about cc.net parse logs but this was don't has positive result.

What kind of ways i should use for resolve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ccnet config, in the project, at the top of the tasks block:

```
<modificationWriter>
 <filename>svn_mods.xml</filename>
 <path>c:\modsdir</path>
</modificationWriter>
```

This will write the SVN modifications to a file.

Next in the tasks block:

```
<nant>
 <executable>c:\path_to_nant</executable>
 <buildFile>mybuildfile.build</buildFile>
 <targetList>
  <target>conditionally_run_nunit_tests</target>
 </targetList>
</nant>
```

This will run a Nant task after the modificationwriter task.

In **conditionally_run_nunit_tests**, search the file **c:\modsdir\svn_mods.xml** for **#runautotest**. If you find it, run the tests. If you don't find it then do nothing. There are various ways to parse the mods file. You could use C# script to read the entire file into a string and then call Contains passing in #runautotest.

The below code is an example of using C# script in Nant. SearchFile opens a file, reads it into a string and checks if a value is in the string. It returns "yes" or "no". The below script is untested.

```
<property name="yesno" value="${ns::SearchFile("c:\modsdir\svn_mods.xml", "#runautotest")}"/>

<script language="c#" prefix="ns">
    <references>
        <include name="System"/>
        <include name="System.IO"/>
    </references>
    <code>
    <![CDATA[   
    [Function("SearchFile")]
    public static string SearchFile(string filepath, string token) 
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filepath);
        string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
        myFile.Close();
        if(myString.Contains(token)) return "yes";
        else return "no";
    }               
    ]]>
    </code>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question's upvotes indicate, this seems to be a more important issue. I will give it a try: As far as I understood the setting, CCNET is the [leader of the pack](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_of_the_Pack), monitoring SVN for source code changes, getting the sources, triggering MSBuild to build them and triggering NUnit and WebDriver to execute unit and web tests.

Decision on whether to execute the tests or not is made dependent on a defined hashtag in the SVN modification comments. SVN on the one side and NUnit and WebDriver on the other are coupled through CCNET only.

So first of all I would assure that this hashtag containing comment is available in CCNET somewhere. I'm not an SVN expert but I would assume that all comments are in the CCNET modifications log. Can you verify this?

Next the execution of the tests needs to be made conditional. Configuration of CCNET is a rather static thing. Granted with the advent of [DynamicValues](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters) in CCNET 1.5 and [ConditionalTasks](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Conditional_Task) in CCNET 1.6 the configuration got more dynamic and you now have flow of control in CCNET as well, but since I'm somewhat old-fashioned I would advocate wrapping test execution in a build script using e.g. MSBuild or NAnt and put modification log evaluation in there.

**Update**: Have a look at [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420058/38029). This example is pretty close to what I had in mind (although I would have used [`<xmlpeek>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/xmlpeek.html) instead of [`<script>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/script.html)).